# Combining parameter expansion with modifiers in zsh

Tags: zsh, variable-substitution

Say I have the following

```
$f1=/some/path
$f2=/some/subpath
$f3=/some/other/subpath
```

If I try:

```
test1=${$f1/$f2/${f3:t}}
```

zsh complains with `bad substitution`.

However:

```
test2=${f3:t}
```

works well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `${file:t:r}` is how to combine modifiers in parameter expansions. `${file:t:r}` removes the path and removes the extension from `file`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the extra `$` in front of `f1`. Try:

```
test1=${f1/$f2/${f3:t}}
```